# define a variable in irb console from inside a class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, irb

How to define a variable that exists in irb console from inside a class?

I want to accomplish something like this:

```
class MyClass
    def self.define_var_in_irb
       # of course this doesn't work because a is a local variable,
       # not in the irb scope, and thats my question, how I can define 
       # a variable into the current irb session from inside a class.

       a = 'hello' 

    end
end

>> MyClass.define_var_in_irb
>> puts a 
# 'hello'
```

Comment: *I'm actually monking patching a rails model*--Then your question has nothing to do with irb, so quit confusing the issue.  And do you think writing `r = self.find param` v. `r = 'hello'` somehow clarifies your issue?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What problem are you trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: Given the actual question posed *"Is possible to create a class that define a variable in irb console? "* Would **Yes** be an acceptable answer for you? If not maybe try and pose a different question.

Comment: I just want to monkey patch while using the irb console. Why? because we have an application that require accesing the data directly on IRB console, and we all time do thinks like a = SomeModel.find(xxx) (Is not only that). So we want to have some method that speed up our work, and defining variables in irb from inside a class is something that would help us a lot. @engineersmnky, not thats not an acceptable answer, I've edited my question. please try a different answer.

Comment: First of all you are defining an unused local variable which has no impact in this context. Based on your outline the answer is no. Local variables are scoped and it will be discarded as soon as the method returns. You could define instance variables (e.g. `instance_variable_set` or simply `@r =`) but this will still be scoped inside the receiver. So now the precise answer based on the updated question is No.

Comment: i know I'm defining a local variable, I was wondering, what is the class that holds the variables at IRB, for example, if i'm in irb and do `self` i got `#<Object:0x7f2777b482a0`, so, its not possible to `use instance_variable_set` or `instance_eval` to set a variable on the irb console?

Comment: in irb `self` returns `main` which would be the contextual defining Object. You can certainly use `instance_variable_set` or `instance_eval` but this seems far more painful than `a = SomeModel.find(xxx)` since to do this you would have to be in the context of `main` e.g. opening an irb console anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If your only goal is to set some console variables, then there are alternative tools for this.

If you used `pry` (which you should, BTW), you'd be able to use `.pryrc` for this. Create your local variables there.

```
r = Revision.find whatever
```

This file will be picked up and evaluated by Pry when it starts up. Just put it in your project dir (or HOME).

IRB uses `.irbrc` file, but doesn't expose local variables from it. Instance variables will work, however. Also, it doesn't load the local file (only global one, from HOME)